# Creating a simple menubar, menu and menu item in C using GTK4

Tags: c, gtk4

I created a simple C application using GTK4 that has a window, a menubar, a menu, and a menu item. I would like the menu to read "File" and the menu item underneath File to read "Connect". How can I code the menus and menubar so that I have a menu File->Connect?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void connect(GApplication *app, gpointer *data) {
    puts("Connect menu item clicked.\n");
}

static void activate(GApplication *app, gpointer *data) {
    GtkWidget *win = gtk_application_window_new(GTK_APPLICATION(app));
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "IRC Client");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(win), 800, 800);

    GSimpleAction *act_connect = g_simple_action_new("Connect", NULL);
    g_action_map_add_action(G_ACTION_MAP(app), G_ACTION(act_connect));
    g_signal_connect(act_connect, "activate", G_CALLBACK(connect), NULL);

    GMenu *menubar = g_menu_new();
    GMenuItem *menu_item_menu = g_menu_item_new("File", NULL);
    GMenu *menu = g_menu_new();
    GMenuItem *menu_item_connect = g_menu_item_new("Connect", "app.connect");
    g_menu_append_item(menu, menu_item_connect);
    g_object_unref(menu_item_connect);
    g_menu_item_set_submenu(menu_item_menu, G_MENU_MODEL(menu));
    g_menu_append_item(menubar, menu_item_menu);
    g_object_unref(menu_item_menu);

    gtk_application_set_menubar(GTK_APPLICATION(app), G_MENU_MODEL(menubar));
    gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar(GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW(win), TRUE);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(win));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int stat;

    app = gtk_application_new("com.ircclient", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    stat = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return stat;
}
```

Comment: Removal of the menu and toolbar widgets in Gtk+3 wasn't the stroke of genius it was supposed to be. Comparatively, it's frustratingly difficult to style the stand-in menu in Gtk4 with  icons, accelerators, spacing and themes. At least that has been my experience.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin:  You should not style applications, except for the displayed content.

Comment: @Lothar -- therein lies the whole problem with the direction Gtk has taken. The is no one-size fits all widget library or approach to UI design/layout. I have particular spacing requirements for the UIs I write, and no, Gtk4 doesn't know better than I do how I want my UI displayed.  With Gtk+2, it was simple to customize spacing down to the pixel. With Gtk+3 and Gtk4 that capability was lost. CSS theming was not a workable substitute, especially when each new minor-version release broke backward compatibility with the last. A bumpy ride it has been...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it’s not only gtk. All desktop toolkits removed styling, gtk was the last one.

Comment: Yes, true, just try and set the font size of the date and time shown in the systray on plasma.... The fiasco for both major desktops hails back to the same flawed design decisions made in 2007. Gnome2 and KDE3 were at the pinnacle of their development cycles and both a dream to use. With the tablet market just exploding, both desktops made a one-desktop-for-all design decision to rewrite and style so the desktops would work on either a PC or smaller mobile/tablet format. To make both work, the trade-offs crippled the PC desktop. And neither ever saw use on the smaller screens. Idiots.

Answer (score 4):

First let us start with your `connect` callback function, its prototype should look like this:

```
static void connect ( GSimpleAction *simple_action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer *data
```

After that, you have one small problem, and you are good to go.
Here on this line:

```
GSimpleAction *act_connect = g_simple_action_new("Connect", NULL);
```

This is your first parameter called `"Connect"`.

And here on this line:

```
GMenuItem *menu_item_connect = g_menu_item_new("Connect", "app.connect");
```

The second parameter is `"app.connect"`, now if you compare `"Connect"`with `"app.connect"` you will notice the mistake.

It is case-sensitive, just replace `"Connect"` with `"connect"` and you should be fine.

Now to your question, you need another menu for that, try to understand the following Demo:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void action_clbk ( GSimpleAction *simple_action, G_GNUC_UNUSED GVariant *parameter, G_GNUC_UNUSED gpointer *data )
{
    g_print ( "The action %s was clicked.\n", g_action_get_name ( G_ACTION ( simple_action ) ) );
}

static void activate ( GApplication *app, G_GNUC_UNUSED gpointer *data )
{
    GtkWidget *win;
    GSimpleAction *act_connect;
    GSimpleAction *act_disconnect;

    /// ***
    GMenu *menu_bar;
    GMenu *network_menu;
    GMenu *server_menu;

    /// ***
    GMenuItem *menu_item_connect;
    GMenuItem *menu_item_disconnect;

    /// *** Menu Bar
    menu_bar = g_menu_new();

    /// *** Network_Menu
    network_menu = g_menu_new();
    g_menu_append_submenu ( menu_bar, "Network", G_MENU_MODEL ( network_menu ) );

    /// *** Server_Menu
    server_menu = g_menu_new();
    g_menu_append_submenu ( network_menu, "Server", G_MENU_MODEL ( server_menu ) );
    /// ***
    win = gtk_application_window_new ( GTK_APPLICATION ( app ) );
    gtk_window_set_title ( GTK_WINDOW ( win ), "IRC Client" );
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( GTK_WINDOW ( win ), 400, 400 );

    /// *** Create Connect and Disconnect Actions
    act_connect    = g_simple_action_new ( "connect", NULL );
    act_disconnect = g_simple_action_new ( "disconnect", NULL );

    /// *** Add them to the ActionMap
    g_action_map_add_action ( G_ACTION_MAP ( app ), G_ACTION ( act_connect ) );
    g_action_map_add_action ( G_ACTION_MAP ( app ), G_ACTION ( act_disconnect ) );

    /// *** Connect them to the activate Signal
    g_signal_connect ( act_connect,    "activate", G_CALLBACK ( action_clbk ), NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( act_disconnect, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( action_clbk ), NULL );

    /// *** Create the Connect Item
    menu_item_connect = g_menu_item_new ( "Connect", "app.connect" );
    g_menu_append_item ( server_menu, menu_item_connect );

    /// *** Create the Disconnect Item
    menu_item_disconnect = g_menu_item_new ( "Disconnect", "app.disconnect" );
    g_menu_append_item ( server_menu, menu_item_disconnect );

    /// ***
    gtk_application_set_menubar             ( GTK_APPLICATION ( app ), G_MENU_MODEL ( menu_bar ) );
    gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar ( GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW ( win ), TRUE );

    /// ***
    gtk_window_present ( GTK_WINDOW ( win ) );

    /// *** Clean
    g_object_unref ( act_connect );
    g_object_unref ( act_disconnect );
    g_object_unref ( menu_item_connect );
    g_object_unref ( menu_item_disconnect );
    g_object_unref ( server_menu );
    g_object_unref ( network_menu );
    g_object_unref ( menu_bar );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int stat;

    /// ***
    app = gtk_application_new ( "com.ircclient", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_signal_connect ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( activate ), NULL );

    /// ***
    stat = g_application_run ( G_APPLICATION ( app ), argc, argv );
    g_object_unref ( app );

    /// ***
    return stat;
}
```

Comment: This does not work with LibAdWait application windows.